# How to create page layout for lightning?

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, pagelayoutassignment

I need to create a different page layout to Account object for Lightning  experience. I need to differ the page layout from classic. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is natively not possible. You need to use VF page and You can display conditionally based on whether the user is in Classic or Lightning:

[Render a Visualforce Page Conditionally for the User Interface](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-lightning-programmatic/steps/programmatic-step-2)